# Prove that if p and q are positive distinct primes,then $\log_p(q)$ is irrational.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that if p and q are positive distinct primes,then $\log_p(q)$ is irrational.

Attempt:

Proof by contradiction: Assume  $\log_p(q)$ is rational.

Suppose $\log_p(q) = \dfrac{m}{n}$ where $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\gcd(m,n) = 1$.

Then, $p^{\frac{m}{n}} = q$ which implies $p^m = q^n$.

Comment: And you find the contradiction since $p$ doesn't divide $q^n$.

Comment: You don't even need $\gcd(m,n) = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is very little left to do.  You almost finished the problem.

Assume without loss of generality that $n$ is nonnegative.  $n$ can't be $0$ because you can't divide by zero, so $n>0$.  Therefore $q^n$ is an integer multiple of $q$.  Now $p^m$ is an integer multiple of $q$, which is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

On the RHS you have $n$  $q's$, while on the other side you have $m$ $p's$. Is it possible to have an equation if $p$ and $q$ are coprime number?